# How to create an object from a class inside another class

Tags: php, class, object, require-once, createobject

I have a problem creating an object from another class inside the constructor of my kernel class, it gives a fatal error which says can not find the class, anybody can help please? I do not know what is wrong?

```
namespace App\Http;

use App\Http\Config;
use App\Controllers;

class kernel{
    protected $controller = "HomeController";
    protected $action = "index";
    protected $params=[];
public function __construct(){
        $url = $this->ParseUrl();
        $format_url = ucfirst($url[0]) . "Controller";

        if (file_exists(Config::CONTROLLERS_PATH . $format_url . ".php")) {
            $this->controller = $format_url;
         }
//        $path = Config::CONTROLLERS_PATH . $this->controller . ".php";
//        echo "path: $path";// path is correct

    require_once (Config::CONTROLLERS_PATH . $this->controller . ".php");
//        $include_file = get_required_files();
//        var_dump($include_file);//require_once is working
//here is the problem
    $this->controller = new $this->controller;
}

 public function ParseUrl(){
        if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
        return explode("/", rtrim($_GET['url'], "/"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As the error says  : *the class is not found* ! require_once will throw a fatal if the file you trying to require does not exists

Comment: This looks like some kind of framework and frameworks have their own ways to load classes, typically with an autoloader. Could you specify what exact framework are you using?

Comment: @EriksKlotins  I do not use any frameworks. I just started to learn php and this project can help me to get ready to learn Laravel.